# send multiple files as email in background in Android

Tags: android, email

I have a folder in that folder in have 5 files. I want to sent that all the five files separately in mail. I can able to read the files using below code:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folderName");
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
```

And for sending Email I have Email class

```
public class SendAttachment {
    private String to = "to@gmail.com";//change accordingly
    private String bcc = "someMail@gmail.com";//change accordingly
    private final String user = "from@gmail.com";//change accordingly
    private final String password = "********";//change accordingly
    private Properties properties;
    private String TAG = SendAttachment.class.getSimpleName();

    public SendAttachment(){
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    }

    public String sendEmailNow(String imagepath, Context mContext){

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        });

        //2) compose message
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
          //  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,new InternetAddress());
            message.setSubject("Doctor mobile: "+"<"+ Helper.getInstance().getStringPref(mContext,"docnum")+">");

            //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart1.setText("Please find attached Rx.");

            //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();

            String filename = imagepath;//change accordingly
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

            //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
            //6) set the multiplart object to the message object
            message.setContent(multipart);

            //7) send message
            Transport.send(message);
            deleteFile(imagepath);
            //mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, CheckImages.class));
            return "success";

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "not sent");
            mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, CheckImages.class));
            return "failed";
        }

    }

    public boolean deleteFile(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        return file.delete();
    }
```

I am calling  sendEmailNow(String imagepath, Context mContext) method is ASync Task . it's taking only one image. after that its not working.

Could any one help me. My question is inside the Loop how to call the Async Task. after Async task completed then only next item should send ,

Comment: Please describe "after that its not working"

Comment: the folder has one image its working , if it has more then one image its not working